# How to create web services in yii?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii

I am new to Yii framework, so need some help to rewrite my php/soap web services in yii.
I have found out that Yii provides CWebService for this purposes.

I have created soap server like this before:

```
$server = new SoapServer("WebServiceWSDL.wsdl");

$server->addFunction('myfunction');

$server->handle();

function myfunction(){ ...
}
```

How can I use CWebService?
Some assistance with simple example would be useful to get started.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        class WebServicesForUserController extends Controller
        {

           public function actions()
            {
              // here you need to mention the class for the web service
                return array(
                    'services'=>array(
                        'class'=>  'CWebServiceAction',
                    )
                );
            }
        // these comments are used by Yii to create wsdl for you. The following functions is a webservice
              /**
                 * 
                 * @return datetime this is the current timestamp of the server
                 * @soap
                 */
                public function giveTimestamp()
                {
                    $query='select current_timestamp();';
                    $record=  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
                    return $record;
                }

    // this action is created to consume the webservice.
If you will visit this action then you will get the timestamp which is sent to you as a webservice response

             public function actionLets()
                {
                   ini_set ( 'soap.wsdl_cache_enable' , 0 ); ini_set ( 'soap.wsdl_cache_ttl' , 0 );
                    $wsdlURL='http://localhost/project/webServicesForUser/services';
                    $client=new SoapClient($wsdlURL);
                    $result=$client->giveTimestamp();
                    echo $result;
                }

        }
```

**Note:-If you want to see the wsdl just go to the url in your browser which you used to create soap object**

Comment: How to use CWebService with my own wsdl? Could you give example?